# Fix phone image and reduce magnifying issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am still learning bootstrap and have gone a little far to create a page, I am stuck on 2 things, first one is the phone image at the top section, on my screen it is fine which is 24" with 1600 resolution, but on 15" lcd the phone cuts in half, can someone tell me what to do ? how to fix this ? secondly the images , sections look so magnified so big, does it have any fix ? should I place it in a container ?

Live page : https://babaraliseehar.com/chet/

I have created a single bootstrap page but I am having a little issue in responsiveness.

```
<section class="section hero-section position-relative" id="a">
    <div class="container-fluid position-absolute h-100  hero-bg mob-hid">
        <div class="row align-items-stretch h-100">
            <div class="col-md-6 hero-left"> </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 hero-right"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="col-md-7 p-0 hero-left-img wow fadeInLeft mob-hid" data-wow-delay=".1s">
        <img src="assets/images/front-left2.png" alt="">
    </div> -->
    <div class="col-12 p-0 hero-mob d-none m-block">
        <img src="assets/images/front-left2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-stretch">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-7 hero-right-text wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.3s; animation-name: fadeInRight;">
                <h1>Get better, together.</h1>
                <p>A professional development social network <br> for today's audience: share what you are <br> doing, in the moment, to get better. </p>
                <div id="form_first">
                    <div class="beta-available">
                        <p><strong>Join the list for the next beta release!</strong></p>

                        <form method="post">
                            <div class="form-bx">
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="input-bx input-brd txtEmail" placeholder="Email Address" id="txtEmail_first">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-bx ">

                                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn button-blue btnValidate_first ">
                                    <span class="">Sign Up</span>
                                </button>

                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: about second issue, do you mean  it seems magnified on 15" only, or it seems magnified at anyy size?

Comment: also the video is off in bigger screens(zoom to 25% by "cntrl and -" to simulate it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

image is croped because you used `background-size: cover;`. if you don't want image to get cropped,
use:

```
background-size: contain;
```

also in your layout, image should be on right. so add:

```
background-position-x: right;
```

to your image as well.

---

Also if you want your image to crop, but you want the right side to be always visible, let it to be cover, and use `background-position-x: right;` to crop only left side.

Comment: Thank you I did that, it did fix the cutting issue, but now there is free space on the left side, also when i change the window size to responsive check, the design is destroyed.

Comment: @BabarAli let `background-size: cover;` to be as it is , and use only `background-position-x: right;` (added in answer.)

Comment: @BabarAli your welcome. what about magnify issue? i use my 15" laptop alot and there is some websites like yours that is magnifed on my laptop, but i think you can avoid it with using "em" font sizes, not px. to make font sizes responsive.

Comment: I will try the em font sizes.

Comment: @BabarAli oops, i was wrong. `vw` is responsive font text size. (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_text.asp) but i think that's not common, i didn't saw websites to use vw. alternatively you can use media queries to make font/img/section sizes different on different sizes.(https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp). also you can use `padding: 50px` for images to make them smaller.